# iOS dark mode and theme

Tags: ios

Is it bad design for an app to have both **dark mode** and **themes**?
My app supports dark mode but I also want iOS 12 users to be able to change the theme (`userInterfaceStyle` `dark` was introduced in iOS 13).

Comment: I think this can help you.
https://medium.com/@mczachurski/ios-dark-theme-9a12724c112d

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange for UX by the way: https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is bad design to use both. You already mentioned that you want to support users that are running your app on devices that are not (perhaps: capable of) running iOS 13. Also, you might consider allowing iOS 13 users to ignore the system set `userInterfaceStyle`; e.g. a user might want to run iOS on dark system settings, but still want to view your app in a 'light theme'.

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad to support dark theme for iOS 12 and dark mode for iOS 13.
 If you already support theme support you no need to implement dark mode for iOS 13 again. Just add this listener in your view controller and trigger theme change.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_      previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    if self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark{
        // EnableDarkTheme
    }
    else{
        // disable dark theme
     }
}
```